# Haskell: Creating a list of equivalents

Tags: haskell

I want to create a function with the following definition.

```
equivalent :: Eq a => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

A definition of equivalent.
Three integers x, y, p
x mod p == y mod p then x and y are equivalent.
else x and y are not equivalent.

Case: p = 3,
`equivalent eq [1..10]` returns the list `[[3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8]]`
`eq` is a function that requires two integer and returns True/False.

Would you guide me how to create the function in Haskell?

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: I tried to extract two values from [1 ... 10] and try to make equivalence judgment with the function eq, but I did not know how to pass a function with two arguments to `filter`.

Comment: I misunderstood about `Eq` and I will rethink.

Comment: Related: [How to group similar items in a list using Haskell?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12398458)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution.

1. Pop off the first element of the list (`x`).
2. Use `partition` to split the rest of the list into elements that *are* equivalent to `x` (`group`) and elements that *aren't* equivalent to `x` (`others`).
3. `x:group` is the first group we've found, and then we recurse on the `others`.

---

```
import Data.List (partition)

equivalent :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
equivalent eq = go
  where
    go [] = []
    go (x:xs) =
      let (group, others) = partition (eq x) xs
      in  (x:group) : go others
```

Demonstrated use:

```
>>> import Data.Function (on)
>>> equivalent ((==) `on` (`mod` 3)) [1..10]
[[1,4,7,10],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

By the way, here's another way to accomplish the same thing, which I suspect is faster:

```
>>> fmap (fmap snd) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sort . fmap (\i -> (i `mod` 3, i)) $ [1..10]
[[3,6,9],[1,4,7,10],[2,5,8]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I just started studying Haskell. Thanks again

Comment: Sorting isn't the best you can do for the modular arithmetic example. Sorting is O(n log n), where n is the number of elements processed. If you use `Data.Map` with remainders as keys and lists of numbers as values, you can get O(n log m), where n is the number of values and m is the number of *distinct* remainders. When applicable, `Data.IntMap` will almost certainly be much faster with an O(n) bound that's not quite so easy to characterize tightly. (You can view it as O(n) with a fairly large constant factor, but in practice it typically performs much better than that would suggest).

Answer (score 0):

One other way of performing this job would be to use [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:filter) and [`(\\)` (difference)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:-92--92-) functions over lists. So the following recursive code should suffice.

```
groupByRemaindersOf :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupByRemaindersOf _ []     = []
groupByRemaindersOf p (x:xs) = let ys = x : filter (\y -> y `rem` p == x `rem` p) xs in ys : groupByRemaindersOf p (xs \\ ys)

*Main> groupByRemaindersOf 3 [1..10]
[[1,4,7,10],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Although this seems to be faster than any algorithm involving `sort`, i believe folding with a `Map` type as an accumulator might still do better than this.